# Doctrine2/Symfony: Different connections for entity and sequence

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I've a problem with sequences in Symfony/Doctrine2:

- Sequence (*sq_company*) is stored on central server.
- Entity table (*company*) is stored on different server (will be sharded soon).

When Doctrine persists an entity, it uses the same connection for entity table and sequence access.

Writing custom sequence generator gives no help, because:

```
public function generate(EntityManager $em, $entity)
{
    $em->getConnection(); // Entity storage connection, no chance to access the other
}
```

As i understand, it's not possible to inject something (sequence connection from dbal settings, in this case) to the sequence generator.

Any ideas?

Thanks for help.

---

P.S.: Let's say i will use Redis storage for sequence generation. How will i do that without any access to other services from sequence generator? It's odd, maybe i am doing something wrong (anc injection is possible)? Or maybe i should look at lower/higher abstraction level?

Comment: Use two different entity managers and or connections.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

Comment: Different entity manager for sequences? What?